# CSS: Full height container on WP Twenty Fourteen

Tags: css, wordpress, containers

I haven't had any problems with full height containers before, at least I remember so. But, recently I have been having problems with customizing Twenty Fourteen theme that comes with Wordpress.

What I am trying to do here is to set the right side bar height to same as content div.

I tried setting height to 100% for both parent div and sidebar div, but it does nothing.

The site is: http://www.poke.ge

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: The percentage is worked out from the parents height value, so if the parents parent doesn't have a value it's not going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix would be to have your "#main" element be relatively positioned, and your "#secondary" element be absolutely positioned with "height: 100%;".

```
#main {
    position: relative;
}
#secondary {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

But keep in mind the padding of "#secondary" will add to its height. A solution could be to have "box-sizing: border-box" property assigned to it.